# Get result bytes from a IPP request in PHP

Tags: php, printing

I'm writing a PHP procedure to request the printer status to get the paper-end or paper-near flags.
The procedure is based on PrintIPP class.

I build a buffer with the custom command bytes, set the data by setData() function and 'print' by `printJob()` function.

I need to get the printer response but I don't know-how.

The `$ipp->status` returns the status of the operation equal **successfull-ok** and the `$ipp->response_completed` is equal **completed**: but I need to parse the raw bytes.

How can I retrieve them?

Comment: What exactly is "`PrintIPP` class"?

Comment: It is this library: http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/